# 404 resource not found adding jsp file

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm working on a Spring MVC project. There's a Home.jsp page that works fine and I have to add a button on that page that will open a new jsp page for entering a new employee. I added the HTML and javascript to the Home.jsp and created my NewEmpInput.jsp. But when I click the button I get 404 Resource not found. You can see my window.open function here:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Our custom styling! -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/mainStyle.css'/>">
<!-- Our custom javascript! -->                         
<script src="<c:url value='/resources/javascript/commentModal.js'/>" ></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/resources/javascript/activeFilters.js'/>" ></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/resources/javascript/searchFilters.js'/>" ></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/WEB-INF/views/NewEmpInput.jsp'/>" ></script>

<script >var newEmpWindow;
    function openWin() {
    newEmpWindow = window.open("/WEB-INF/views/NewEmpInput.jsp", "left=300, width=800, height=400, top=200");}
</script>

</head>
<body>
```

Comment: The Home.jsp and NewEmpInput.jsp are in the same folder in eclipse project.

Comment: In your case, why don't you create a request mapping in your controller and in the window.open function pass the url(requestmapping to that method).

Answer (score 0):

The application server won't let anyone into the `WEB-INF` folder - that folder is protected from any access via http(s).

I'm not sure about this, but try if that page can be reached at just `/NewEmpInput.jsp`.

Comment: Tried just /NewEmpInput.jsp, but still 404 error. The Home.jsp file is in that folder and that works, so why wouldn't my jsp work? Could it be because Home is added to one of the xml files?

Comment: Yes, some configuration will probably be needed. Try to look at the page that's working and configure this new one in a similar way. Hopefully someone with knowledge of Spring MVC will post a proper answer eventually.

Comment: I'll have to research more, but I think there may be 3 entries/pieces that are needed to display a jsp file. Maybe a Controller, a Revolver, and a Mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Turns out I had to create a controller for the new jsp page just like there is for the current home.jsp page. Here's the code:

```
@Controller
public class NewEmployeeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "NewEmpInput")
    public String newEmployee() {
        //model.addAttribute("resultBoard", "resultBoard");
        return "NewEmpInput";
    }
}
```

Then my java script in the current home.jsp page worked like this:

```
<script >var newEmpWindow;
    function openWin() {
    newEmpWindow = window.open("/MyProjName/NewEmpInput.html", "left=300, width=800, height=400, top=200");}
</script>
```